# How can I create a new array by iterating an existing array over a json config 'key'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of numbers in a string in an array named `data` and cannot figure out how to use the `data` to iterate over my JSON named `key`.

I've attempted some variations of a for loop, but am not able to:

1. Strip out the desired data, it shows up errors for numbers
2. I haven't been able to design a loop which iterates over the array values, just 1 to 5. The array changes so it could be `["5", "2", "3"]`

Is anyone able to please help? Many thanks.

```
   var key = {
    "1" : "ID 1: Steve",
    "2" : "ID 2: Bob",
    "3" : "ID 3: Paul",
    "4" : "ID 4: Spencer",
    "5" : "ID 5: Jimmy"}; 

   data = ["1", "3", "5"]
```

desired output:
`["ID 1: Steve", "ID 3: Paul", "ID 5: Jimmy"]`

Comment: what's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the `data` array and get all the values from the object `key` as an array, here is an example

```js
var key = {
    "1" : "ID 1: Steve",
    "2" : "ID 2: Bob",
    "3" : "ID 3: Paul",
    "4" : "ID 4: Spencer",
    "5" : "ID 5: Jimmy"
};

var data = ["1", "3", "5"];

var newArr = data.map(n => key[n]);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using: [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate on properties of `key`. Then if that property exists via [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in `data` add it to `result`

```js
let key = {
    "1": "ID 1: Steve",
    "2": "ID 2: Bob",
    "3": "ID 3: Paul",
    "4": "ID 4: Spencer",
    "5": "ID 5: Jimmy"
};

let data = ["1", "3", "5"];

let result = [];

for (const k in key) {
    if (data.includes(k)) {
        result.push(key[k]);
    }
}

console.log("result::", result);
```

A better approach based on comments: Iterate on `data` [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and pick value from `key` object

```js
let key = {
    "1": "ID 1: Steve",
    "2": "ID 2: Bob",
    "3": "ID 3: Paul",
    "4": "ID 4: Spencer",
    "5": "ID 5: Jimmy"
};

let data = ["1", "3", "5"];

let result = [];

for (const d of data) {
    result.push(key[d]);
}

console.log("result::", result);
```

Comment: Don't you think that it's useless to loop over the `key` object and each time check if the array `data` has that property as an item, instead you should loop over the `data` array and just get what's needed from the `key` object

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `reduce` to achieve this:

```js
const key = {
    "1" : "ID 1: Steve",
    "2" : "ID 2: Bob",
    "3" : "ID 3: Paul",
    "4" : "ID 4: Spencer",
    "5" : "ID 5: Jimmy"}; 

const data = ["1", "3", "5"];

const result = data.reduce((accum, i) => {
  accum.push(key[i]);

  return accum;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var key = {
    "1" : "ID 1: Steve",
    "2" : "ID 2: Bob",
    "3" : "ID 3: Paul",
    "4" : "ID 4: Spencer",
    "5" : "ID 5: Jimmy"}; 
  //  const desired = ["ID 1: Steve", "ID 3: Paul", "ID 5: Jimmy"]
  const data = ["1", "3", "5"]

    const result = []
    const values = Object.values(key)
    //console.log(values);
    data.forEach(item => {
        values.forEach(val => {
            if (val.includes('ID ' + item + ':')) {
                result.push(val)
            }
        })
    })

    console.log(result);
```